# Question regarding the fourier series, the L2 space of square integrable functions and convergence.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, normed-spaces

I have been self learning the fourier series and if anyone can help me with my questions that will be super great!

1. Firstly, why is the fourier series defined on the L2 space and not on other spaces? is it because it is the only space that's a Hilbert space and  hence it has an inner product which then allows us to get the coefficients for the series?.
2. This implies that whenever we try to approximate a function with the fourier series, the function should be from the L2 space so that we get
   the convergence in norm. However, why is it that in most applications of the fourier series this is not proved in the first place? (i.e. we should show that the function we are trying to approximate is actually square integrable?) Is it because alot of functions are square integrable? Or is it that we can simply plot the partial fourier sums and see if it converges or diverges?
3. Is there an easy way to tell if a function is square integrable?

Comment: 2) and 3) A continuous function on a compact interval is bounded and hence square integrable.

Comment: 1) The heart and soul of "Fourier series" is that $\cos n\theta, \sin n\theta$ for all $n \in \Bbb N$ form an orthogonal set under the inner product $\int_0^{2\pi}f(\theta)g(\theta)\,d\theta$, so we are talking about an inner product space. And when you are dealing with limits, having a complete space is extremely useful. Thus, Hilbert.

Answer (score 1):

In practical applications, the functions being expanded are piecewise smooth at worst, and the Fourier series converges uniformly for such functions, at least on closed intervals where the functions are continuous. So, square integrability doesn't usually come up in beginning presentations, and it doesn't need to.

Parseval discovered that the square of the Fourier coefficients was equal to the integral of the square of the function being expanded, and that happened even before pointwise convergence results were proved for the Fourier series, and a full century before an abstract inner product was defined. Parseval's result undoubtedly motivated the idea of studying square integrable functions.

It is remarkable thing that the Fourier series maps $L^2[0,2\pi]$ onto $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$. But these spaces weren't defined until long after the original pioneers were dead. Pointwise results were the main focus for a long time.